# Spring Boot Hibernate Problem with generating entity ID using sequence or identity

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am developed Rest API with sprint boot, jpa, hibernate and PostgreSQL. My goal is to be able to generate auto-incremented id for using with code and using database tool such as D Beaver without writing any extra queries for getting next ID value and etc.

I have created entity `User`. I tried generating id in two ways:

1. GenerationType.IDENTITY

When using GenerationType.IDENTITY it successfully creates table with name `user`, sequence with name `user_id_seq` and adds a default value for `user.id` column `nextval('user_id_seq'::regclass)`. Everything in database is as expected and it works great with database tool, but problem occurs when I am trying to insert new row from my API. When trying to insert new row hibernate executes query

```
select currval('user_id_seq')
```

to get id value and I am getting error

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid name syntax
```

because of those quotes around `user`. It should execute

```
select currval('user_id_seq')
```

I believe that the problem here is because I use table name `user` which is a reserved keyword, but I want to keep it this way because this naming matches other tables pattern.

2. GenerationType.SEQUENCE

If I use annotations:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="user_generator", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize=1)
```

it creates table 'user', sequence 'user_id_seq' but doesn't add user.id column default value, so I can't insert new rows using database tool without specifying id value. But using this generation type my API works fine.

It is also worth mentioning that I am using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop` and manually dropping and recreating schema each time so there wouldn't be any unnecessary sequences/tables left.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`user`")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    // other properties...

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // other getters and setters...
}
```

So... It is possible to somehow connect those two ways and create one working solution? I need to have default value for column and that hibernate would also know how to generate that id.

P.S. I don't want to change table/entity naming or execute SQL to correct tables when running application. I believe that there should be a better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of hours of debugging I ended up extending PostgreSQL82Dialect and overriding getIdentitySelectString function to remove quotes from table name.